# Minimize all other windows from the current application?

Tags: windows, browser, desktop, window

How do you minimize all other windows from the current application you are using?

Comment: One way is to minimize all apps (far right bottom corner Windows 10) and then restore the one app you want.

Comment: Another probably possible solution would be a custom autohotkey script. If you already have a collection like Ac'tiv Aid running in the background, it should be possible without much additional work.

Comment: Remember whatever you do to keep it simple. Much goes on with my computer and that is why I use a very simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

You may enable Aero Shake, which lets you quickly minimize all opened
windows, except the current active window, by shaking its title bar.
Shaking the title bar again will restore the other minimized windows.
Shaking is done by a click on the title bar of the window you want to
work with, and while holding the mouse button down, shake the window
back and forth.

Enabling Aero Shake seems to have disappeared from the Settings app,
where it used to be at *System > multi-tasking*.
It can still be enabled from the registry, this way:

- Run *Settings > System > multi-tasking* and verify that "Snap windows"
  is enabled.
  (Snap was required in my tests to make Shake work.)
- Create a `.reg` file containing the following text:

  ```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
    "DisallowShaking"=dword:00000000
  ```
- Double-click the `.reg` file to execute it, and answer OK to
  the permission dialog
- Reboot.

Microsoft seems to be phasing Aero Shake out, so I can't guarantee that
it will keep on working in the years to come.

Answer (score 2):

You can't *minimize all other windows from the **current application*** but you can minimize all the other windows by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. It's still listed in the [Windows 10 keyboard shortcuts list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#ID0EBD=Windows_10)

> <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>: Minimize all except the active desktop window (restores all windows on second stroke).
>
> [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#ID0EBD=Windows_10)

Unfortunately it probably ties to Aero Shake so you need to enable Aero Shake in order to use it

Comment: Just tried this now in Windows 11 and it worked fine.  I see there is an option for "Title bar Window Shake" in the multi-tasking settings still, which was "off", so the shortcut works regardless